# Ormlite inner join in version 4.41

Tags: inner-join, ormlite

I know that inner join operation is only supported from ORMlite version 4.42 and above.  Does there exist a way to replace inner join operation functionality in previous ormlite versions -- without doing separate querys?

Comment: Why is updating to 4.42 a problem?

Comment: It is osgi integrated and updates gives me more troubles with dependecies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do your own joins using raw queries:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

But otherwise the answer is no.